# Exclude PSTs from Windows Desktop Search Indexing in Windows 10 when they are not open in Outlook 365

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, search, search-indexing

Win10/22H2/O365 2302. I have about a dozen PST files that I do not want Windows Desktop Search to index, to keep the index EDB a reasonable size. Historically, I thought WDS did not index PSTs unless they were open in Outlook, but I've noticed recently that WDS is indexing everything, resulting in a very large index, despite (1) the PSTs are not open in Outlook and (2) the folder where the PSTs are stored is not included in indexed locations (and is specifically excluded from indexing under the folder properties).

Is there any way to systematically exclude these PSTs from the index? If I delete them under the registry key HKEY_USERS{SID}\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Search\Catalog, they get re-populated automatically.

I've also tried playing around with the Powershell interface to CrawlScopeManager and adding rules to exclude these PSTs, but it has no effect.

One possible cause is that these PSTs are associated with Outlook profiles other than the default one that is normally open. Does anyone know if WDS will automatically index PSTs that are only listed under non-default/non-open profiles? If so, is there any way to stop this from happening?

Comment: My Search folder is only 2 GB and I have 11 PST archive files (185,000 items indexed).  Outlook files are part of the Index location USERS  and I cannot see how to not index just a small part of this.

Comment: If all of my PSTs are indexed, I end up with well over a million items, which seems to cause problem with index stability. I thought WDS would only index PSTs that are open in Outlook (or in a folder tagged for indexing) but on my box, it seems to be indexing them no matter what I do.

Comment: In Search Index locations, Outlook is separate from Users. You could exclude Outlook and search manually in Outlook.

Comment: I still want to use WDS to search PSTs that are open in Outlook, just exclude the ones that are not. Searching Outlook without indexing is very slow.

Comment: Try to modify the indexing options in the Control Panel. You can do this by searching and opening Control Panel in Windows search bar, clicking on Modify, unchecking Microsoft application/Outlook and clicking on OK. This will stop Windows Search from indexing any Outlook data, including PSTs.

Comment: I don’t want it to exclude all Outlook data, only PSTs associated with the non-default profile that are not typically open in Outlook. The control panel does not have any way to exclude individual profiles or PSTs.